# How do I post this JSON data with PHP? This JSON different

Tags: php, json, curl

This is JSON data

```
{"clanSearch":{"results":[{"tag":"#G90G8RCU","name":"codex2015.asia","type":"open","locationName":"Indonesia","clanBadgeImg":{"s":"https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/FDduXa8Fmz_KmJyPsFTTms00YDykkmlZRu4ev-juBQQ.png, https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/FDduXa8Fmz_KmJyPsFTTms00YDykkmlZRu4ev-juBQQ.png 2x","m":"https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/FDduXa8Fmz_KmJyPsFTTms00YDykkmlZRu4ev-juBQQ.png, https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/FDduXa8Fmz_KmJyPsFTTms00YDykkmlZRu4ev-juBQQ.png 2x","l":"https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/FDduXa8Fmz_KmJyPsFTTms00YDykkmlZRu4ev-juBQQ.png","xl":"https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/FDduXa8Fmz_KmJyPsFTTms00YDykkmlZRu4ev-juBQQ.png"},"warFrequency":"always","clanLevel":1,"clanPoints":6867,"warWins":0,"requiredTrophies":0,"members":12}]}}
```

[Here is the link](https://set7z18fgf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/?route=getClanDetails&clanTag=GG90G8RCU)
and my PHP code

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://set7z18fgf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/?route=getClanSearch&name=codex2015.asia"));
$info = "$json->{'tag'}";
echo $info;
```

In this case, I want to get tag data, but if I run this script I get nothing.

Comment: That's nice. What is your question?

Comment: this json diferent

Comment: What  do you want actually?

Comment: `var_dump($json);` have a look at it , then make you next steps

Comment: reloade page i just edit my post .. im sory about that .. im new on stackoverflow

Comment: and `$info = "$json->{'tag'}"; ` can be `$info = $json->tag; `

Comment: Might also be worth doing a `var_dump()` on that `file_get_contents()` call; if you've not got `allow_url_fopen` set, it's likely to sulk on an URL like that : http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions i try this code but i got error .. like this Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: use `json_decode (file_get_contents(URL),true);` and then all is an array und you can `var_dump()` it

Comment: after that: `$json['clanSearch']['results'][0]['tag']` should work

Comment: thanks @JustOnUnderMillions im successfully get json data with your method :) check this for example [link](http://www.codex2015.asia)

Comment: mr.n0peC, in that case, click the checkmark of the answer to accept it.

Comment: oke @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents("url",true)));
$info =  $json['clanSearch']['results'][0]['tag'];
echo $info;
```

Use`true` flag and the hole data is converted to arrays with sub arrays

If you dont use `true` you have to get it with:

```
$json->clanSearch->results[0]->tag;
```

Comment: thanks very useful :D